# How to block POST requests to a specific URL or text in the Apache access log

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For Example here is the record in the Apache Log that I want to block:

```
75.130.202.149 - - [11/Dec/2015:11:00:01 -0500] "POST /blog/insert_data HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "http://brokerasheville.com/blog/view/broker-asheville-sponsors-the-20th-annual-montford-holiday-tour-of-homes" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36"
```

I want to block anything that has `/blog/` in it.

This is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule (^|/)blog/?$ - [F,L]
```

What am I missing as this won't stop a spam bot from posting to my blogs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks...appreciate your assistance .